# Is it possible to autofix malformed extruded object?

Tags: mesh

I am trying to close the following object:

[image]

I have selected it's edges around opening and pressed `F`. But it gave me

[image]

This means, that object contains malformations like duplicate edges and vertices, infinitisemal slits and so on.

Can I fix this automatically?

Comment: Don't use fill, use grid fill. Fill will create N-gons (faces with more than 4 vertices) and irregular topology.

Comment: If you want a quick way to remove dupes (if there are any), select the whole mesh in edit mode, then press `M` (merge) in the 3D viewport, and select "By Distance"

Comment: @ChristopherBennett will it work or just maybe?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by _will it work_? If there are any duplicate (overlapping) vertices, it should remove them. If they are too far apart, you can increase the merge distance in the operator panel that pops up in the bottom left corner, but be careful not to set it too high or you may delete unwanted vertices. You can see how many were deleted in the bottom right corner.

Comment: FYI the fill didn't work because you didn't select some edges. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZfCs.png To be sure to select everything go into orthographic view along the front or left side, go into wireframe mode and box select the top part of your mesh.